# Creating a .sh file through Batch script and executing .sh file through batch

Tags: unix, batch-file

Below is the part of a batch script that i have created:

```
{
REM ********* CONN SCRIPT CREATION ***************
echo #!/bin/sh >%conn_script%
echo >>%conn_script%

echo if [ %today% -eq 23 ] >>%conn_script%
echo then >>%conn_script%
echo **find . -maxdepth 0 -type f -mtime +0 -exec rm -rf {} \;>>%conn_script%
echo else >>%conn_script%**
echo echo Files are not from previous month >>%conn_script%
echo fi >>%conn_script%
type %conn_script%
::echo bye  >>%conn_script%

echo The sftp_script is:


echo "command: call %executor%\RUN\plink -ssh %host% -batch -l %user% -pw ********** -m %conn_script%"
call %executor%\RUN\plink -ssh %host% -batch -l %user% -pw %password% -m %conn_script% >%logfile%
}
```

I have created a batch script that is creating a .sh file. That sh file is deleting files from a unix server. When batch script is executing sh file it is getting error "find: bad option -maxdepth
find: [-H | -L] path-list predicate-list" from the code which is in BOLD format.

Even i also want to append the log of deleted files in a .txt file which is in my local machine.

I have tried a lot but not able to append the log in .txt file. 
Please provide yours valuable feedback for this issue.
Thanks

Comment: It seems you haven't looked at the `.sh` file - there will be an erroneous `ECHO is on` line. Use `echo:` or `echo.` to output an empty line.

Comment: Here is the sh file:
{
#!/bin/sh 
ECHO is off.
if [ 23 -eq 23 ] 
then 
find . -maxdepth 0 -type f -mtime +0 -exec rm -rf {} \;
else 
echo Files are not from previous month 
fi
}

Comment: Maybe that unix server has different syntax of `find`, for example Solaris had (has?) no such option.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried /usr/xpg4/bin/find (Available in Solaris).

/usr/xpg4/bin/find . -maxdepth 0 -type f -mtime +0 | xargs rm -f